# How to fix Azure Deployment slots issue for App Service?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I've deployed .Net core web application as App Service on Azure. Also I've created test deployment slot that have different connection settings and environment variable. But now production slot redirects on test slot and show the data from second slot. How does it possible?

I've checked that in Kudu envoronment variables both slots has correct connection settings and variable.

If I stop test slot the production site also down.
If I delete test slot the production show 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in "x-ms-routing-name"="test" cookie that automatically set somehow